# Asymptotic expansion of $I(x)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-xt}}{1+t^2}dt$ as $x\rightarrow \infty $

Tags: asymptotics, taylor-expansion

I wish to find the asymptotic expansion of:
$$I(x)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-xt}}{1+t^2}dt$$
as $x\rightarrow \infty $.

I started by "proving" that:
$$ \frac{1}{1+t^2}= \sum_{n=0}^{N}(-1)^nt^{2n} + R_n(t)$$
(I am not allowed to use Watson's lemma :-), which would make it easier).

But how to continue from here?

Comment: Remember you are looking for asymptotic expansion in $x$ not $t$.

Comment: What precision do you need on your series?

Comment: am i wrong, or was this question originally about the case $x\rightarrow 0_+$?

Comment: @tired: No you're not wrong, I made a mayor typo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of thinking and trying I got the following result:
 For abbreviation: $f(t) = \frac {1}{1+t^2}$
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-xt} f(t) dt = \frac {e^{-xt}}{-x} \bigg|_{0}^{\infty} + \frac{1}{x} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-xt}f'(t) dt$$
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-xt} f(t) dt = \frac {1}{x}+\frac {1}{x^2}f'(0) + \frac {1}{x^3}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-xt}f'''(t) dt$$
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-xt} f(t) dt = \frac {1}{x}- \frac {2!}{x^3} +\frac {1}{x^4}f'''(0) + \frac {1}{x^4}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-xt}f^{4}(t) dt$$
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-xt} f(t) dt = \frac {1}{x}- \frac {2!}{x^3} +\frac {4!}{x^5} -\cdots + \frac {1}{x^{2n-1}}f^{2n-1}(0) + \frac{1}{x^{2n}}   \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-xt}f^{2n}(t) dt$$

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to get an asymptotic approximation to this integral is by integration by parts. So,
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x}de^{-xt}\frac{1}{1+t^2}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{2}{x}\int_0^\infty \frac{t}{(1+t^2)^2}e^{-xt}dt
$$
and so on.

Your approach is correct but you have to justify the interchange between summation and integration. If you can do it, the result is the following
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-xt}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nt^{2n}dt\stackrel{?}{=}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{1}{x^{2n+1}}\Gamma(2n+1).
$$
This series is just an asymptotic one.

Comment: How do you go from $\int_0^\infty t^{2n}e^{-xt}dt$ to $\frac{1}{x^{2n+1}}\Gamma (2n+1)$ ? I know that $\Gamma (2n+1) = \int_0^\infty t^{2n}e^{-t}dt$ but I do not understand how you got the $x$ out.

Comment: $\int_0^\infty e^{-xt}t^{2n}dt=\int_0^\infty e^{-z}\left(\frac{z}{x}\right)^{2n}\frac{dz}{x}=\frac{1}{x^{2n+1}}\int_0^\infty e^{-z}z^{2n}dz$

Comment: That is so nicely put. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: @Jon: I thought I got it. But I don’t. Can you help me with the first line? I do understand the $ \frac{1}{x}$ but I can’t get to the $\frac{2}{x} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {t}{(1+t^2)^2} dt$

Comment: The factor 2 comes out from the derivative of $t^2$. Indeed, it is $(t^2)'=2t$.